# Excel Count unique cells and display them in pivot column

Tags: powerquery

Could anyone help tell me how to do it in EXCEL?  I could use pivot sql but not sure how to make it happen in Excel.

Here is initial data

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Type1 |
| 1 | Type2 |
| 2 | Type1 |
| 3 | Type1 |
| 3 | Type2 |
| 4 | Type2 |
| 5 | Type1 |
| 5 | Type2 |

New data layout

| ID | Type1 | Type2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type1 | Type2 |
| 2 | Type1 |  |
| 3 | Type1 | Type2 |
| 4 |  | Type2 |
| 5 | Type1 | Type2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powerquery, it is called Pivot Column

Bring data into powerquery (data .. from table/range)
Right click Type column and duplicate column
Click select the new duplicate column 
Transform .. Pivot Column ... 
For values column pick Type then in Advanced...do not aggregate
File close and load

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(Source, "Type", "Type - Copy"),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Duplicated Column", List.Distinct(#"Duplicated Column"[#"Type - Copy"]), "Type - Copy", "Type")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```